# how to respectively call seven api(s) in react using axios

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I tried to search how to respectively call multiple API(s). because all of my seven API(s) have to access the same file. so, it's cannot call at the same time.

I tried to promise.all() but it doesn't work.

I tried to axios.then(axios.get(something).then(axios.get("something").then())));
it also dosen't work.

```
let requests = [];
requests.push(axios.post(endpoint, data));
requests.push(axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadpersonfile`));
requests.push(axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadcedatafile`));
requests.push(axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadforenseqfile`));
requests.push(axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadforenseqxfile`));
requests.push(axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadforenseqyfile`));
requests.push(axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadisnpsfile`));
Promise.all(requests);
```

this is another try.

```
axios
.post(endpoint, data)
.then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      }).then(
      axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadpersonfile`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      })).then(
      axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadcedatafile`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      })).then(
      axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadforenseqfile`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      })).then(
      axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadforenseqxfile`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      })).then(
      axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadforenseqyfile`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      })).then(
      axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadisnpsfile`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      }))
```

Comment: Yes Promise.all is what you want. Why is it not working?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Promise.all` does only await multiple promises. It doesn't care in what order they resolve, or whether the computations are running in parallel.

By your word `respectively` I am assuming you want to execute apis one after another not **parallely**

You can try following:

```
const executeApis = async() => {
  const res1 = await axios.post(endpoint, data);
  const res2 = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadpersonfile`);
  // other api hits 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation will indicate, [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) will accept an array of promises. You do not need to `await` them, but you will need to `await` the function itself :

```
const results = await Promise.all(
    axios.post(endpoint, data),
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadpersonfile`),
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadcedatafile`),
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadforenseqfile`),
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadforenseqxfile`),
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadforenseqyfile`),
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/uploadisnpsfile`)
);
```

You can now access the result of your queries in `results[<promise number>]`.
Using `Promise.all` will execute all your requests at once while keeping them in order, improving your performances.

Answer (score 0):

in your first example `Promise.all(requests)` returns a `Promise` object, you are not resolving it.

try this

```
Promise.all(requests).then(function(res) {
 console.log(response);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err);
})
```